# conda info --envs doesn't list all my environments

Tags: anaconda

When I run the code,

```
conda info --envs
```

it lists three environments, but I know I have more environments because when I activate other environments (that I remember creating), it works.

Is this an indication that something is wrong with my conda environments?
Is there a way to fix it?

I'm running a windows 10 system. python 3.5 installed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the environments which are not being listed are in some non-standard location, you can always add them to the list of directories to be searched for:

```
conda config --append envs_dirs /path/to/directory/containing/other/environments
```

Comment: In conda 4.0.6, replace `append` with `add`

Answer (score 0):

- conda environments list comes from here: `~/.conda/environments.txt`
  You can add your env path here. WORKS 100%

> ***in UBUNTU you can open terminal and type: `nano ~/.conda/environments.txt`***

activate env: `conda avtivate <path/to/env>` or if you inside project folder on terminal, you can run: `conda activate ./venv`