# conda environment has no name visible in conda env list - how do I activate it at the shell?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have created an environment called B3 inside anaconda-navigator. It works fine if launched from within navigator.

However, when I want to activate it at the shell, I get 'could not find environmnet B3.'

If I use conda env list, the environment is visible but its name is blank. If I try using the file path instead, I get 'Not a conda environment.'

Why is the name missing, and how can I activate it from the shell?
[image]

Comment: You're doing it right, just looks like a typo: `anaconda2` when it should be `anaconda3` in the path.

Comment: What I really need to know is why it doesn't have a name and how can I launch it with conda activate B3 - as I would expect to. It is a pain to type in the whole path.

Comment: Maybe figure out which `conda` is being used.   It looks like there could be confusion between anaconda 2 and anaconda3 or miniconda3 setups, that each might have different defaults.  I get different missing aliases if I use `/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda env list` vs `~/anaconda/bin/conda env list`

Comment: I Think it may be you helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78119770/17745835

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Name-based reference of Conda environments only works for environments located in one of the directories listed in the `envs_dirs` configuration option (see `conda config --describe envs_dirs`). By default this corresponds to the `envs/` subdirectory in the Conda installation.  If you create an env outside of one of these directories, then you cannot use a name to reference it. Instead, one must activate it by its path:

#### Option 0: Activate by Path (Fix OP’s Typo)

```bash
conda activate /home/julianhatwell/anaconda3/envs/B3
```

Note that OP originally had a typo (`anaconda2` should have been `anaconda3`). After pointing this out (see comments to question), the questioner instead requested an answer to:

**“*How to convert a nameless environment to named one?*”**

## Converting to Named Environment

The following are possible ways to enabling name-based activation.

#### Option 1: Clone Into Directory

One option to use `conda activate B3`, is to recreate your **B3** env in the default directory. You can use the `--clone` flag to accomplish this.

```
conda create --clone path/to/the/nameless_env -n named_env
```

#### Option 2: Add Parent Directory

Alternatively, you can add the parent directory of the environment in question to the `envs_dirs` configuration option.

```
conda config --append envs_dirs /path/to/the/parent_dir
```

#### Option 3: Symbolic Link

Another possibility is to create a symbolic link in one to the `envs_dirs` folders to the environment folder. It seems to work, but it is not a common practice, so it may have downsides that are unreported.

Comment: Thank you. can you say why it was created outside the default directory? This is the only one I created manually from within anaconda-navigator. The rest were done by a script from my laptop supplier. Why is conda create not putting my environment into the default directory?

Comment: @julianhatwell I can't give a definitive answer. I'd start by checking whether the Conda-specific variables are different in the two contexts. I.e., check `conda info` perhaps with a verbosity flag.

Comment: How do you clone a nameless env though?

Comment: @Cos the `--clone` argument accepts paths, e.g., `conda create --clone path/to/the/nameless_env -n named_env`.

Comment: I believe Option 2 above should be `conda config --append envs_dirs /path/to/the/parent_dir`

Comment: Please add option 4 : 
conda activate <Folder>
(answer by Nir below). Was the only way to go in my use case.

Comment: @werner the history here is that the OP tried that, but simply had a typo when typing the path. After I pointed that out, the questioner specified that their question really was: “*How to convert a nameless env to a named env?*” And so that’s what I answered. But, because OP never updated, others arrive at this question that simply want what OP was already (incorrectly) doing. I suppose I could add it for quick reference, since it is the answer to the stated question (“*How to activate?*).

Comment: @merv: you are right, that was exactly my intend. People don't care what the original question was if they find a good answer to their's ;-)

Comment: Option 2 is exactly the answer for Orange3

Answer (score 11):

When you create a conda env with --prefix, it will not have a name,
and to give one do the following:

```
# ex path: /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/envs/`
conda config --append envs_dirs <path to env folder here>
```

To activate the environment:

```
conda activate <name of the env>
```

Answer (score 10):

To get the list of the available environments use:

```
conda env list
```

To activate the *nameless* environment use:

```
conda activate <Folder>
```

Comment: This tip just saved me a lot of hassle of recreating a VM, installing GPU drivers etc.
Thanks so much!

Comment: **Minor note:** `conda env list` works by checking the `envs_dirs` directories and a *user-specific* file, `~/.conda/environments.txt`. Path-based environments get tracked by Conda using that file whenever a user creates or activates an environment by a path. There could still be other valid path-based environments on a volume that Conda will never know about unless the user activates them. For example, environments created by other users won't automatically be found.

Comment: how does one delete the nameless environment?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `conda rename` as following (not need to change conda config):

```
$ conda rename -p path/to/env-123 env-123
```

you can get the path with `conda env list`

source:
https://anaconda.cloud/conda-rename-command

Comment: Technically, this "renames" with a lot of quotes, the src environment.
It is actually cloning the environment and removign any alias to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you have ps1 value set to False, which enables prompt change with change of conda environment.

To check run from your ubuntu terminal:

```
$ conda config --show | grep changeps1
```

And set it to True using:

```
$ conda config --set changeps1 True
```

After this, you should see the currently activated conda environment name at the beginning of each prompt. PS - You may have to close and reopen the terminal for this to take effect.

Comment: This is the correct solution when I have nuked my .bashrc and .profile by mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue on `Apple M1 chip` due to `installation of miniforge3 and miniconda` in two different paths.

**My solution [Edit the .bash_profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72983381/10786792)**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @merv , you can also change your envs_dirs by editing `~/.condarc` file directly.
You can use `conda config` command to firstly create this file if it doesn't exist yet.

```
$ cat ~/.condarc
channels:
  - conda-forge
envs_dirs: ['/xxx/xxx/']
```