# conda can't activate existing virtual enivrement

Tags: python, conda, dvc, cookiecutter

I'm trying to learn how to automate data science project using dvc and cookiecutter as project structure, I made conda envirument and installed all my libraries in venv file.
everything was working fine but after I closed project and opened venv enirument is working but can't run dvc, and when tried to deactivate envirument and reactivate it doesn't recognize environment either.
[image: image of the problem]
I can't understand the reason of this problem.

tried to after openning project when venv environment is working to reinstall all my libraries again, but got same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda environment has no name visible in conda env list - how do I activate it at the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527131/conda-environment-has-no-name-visible-in-conda-env-list-how-do-i-activate-it-a)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what does "and installed all my libraries in venv file" mean, **exactly**? What's a venv file?